# Change stream buffer size of a .net/windows application using default 4k

Tags: .net, windows, stream, smb

This might not be the right question or forum, but is there a way to change the default buffer size for file/stream copy operations in a .NET application that is using (presumably) default buffer sizes when you do not have access to the source code?

I am using a program that performs a set of file copies across our WAN but it is very slow. It uses SMB2 to copy files from one place to another using a network UCN path.

On running Wireshark I can see that the files (typically 1mb, across our 100mb WAN with a latency of 7ms) are being split into 4k packets (which is the default buffer size, I believe for .net stream operations), sent to a share using SMB2, there are a fair amount of TCP reconstruction operations being carried out too, and the file transfer is taking about 3 seconds.

I ran a similar operation using file copy and Robocopy and they sent 65k packets, there are absolutely no TCP packet reconstruction operations, just a sequential list of 65k SMB2 requests and it takes milliseconds.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, you are probably seeing the TCP window size.  Nothing to do with .NET.  [Read this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2007.01.cableguy.aspx).

Comment: Ok, but in wireshark it is showing: SBM2 with the packet size of 4096 bytes, during file copy it is showing 65535. The code is using the built in file copy commands from .NET